# how to download generated file using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I'm making program that requires file download. So far i have worked with downloads like http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml. As it is direct link to file i had no problems with it.
But how do I download from http://saraksti.rigassatiksme.lv/?stotele=vef&a=p.search&t=xml&day=1-5&l=lv. All I get is http://saraksti.rigassatiksme.lv/index.html

Sorry for late code. It's a function I use. script is download url. slash variable depends on OS.

```
void PValidatorPlugin::downloadScript(QString script)
{
#ifdef WIN32
        QString slash = "\\";
#else
        QString slash = "/";
#endif
    QFileInfo fileInfo(script);
    QString fileName;
    if(fileInfo.fileName().isEmpty())
    {
        fileName = "pValidator.script";
    } else {
        fileName = fileInfo.fileName();
    }
    QFile file(QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::TempLocation) + slash + fileName);
    if (file.exists())
    {
            return;
    }

    QNetworkAccessManager* m_NetworkMngr = new QNetworkAccessManager(Core::ICore::instance()->mainWindow());
    QUrl aUrl(script);
    QNetworkReply *reply= m_NetworkMngr->get(QNetworkRequest(aUrl));
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),&loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(reply->readAll());

    delete reply;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work with that url ?

Comment: I can second that: show us the code you're using. Without it we'll mostly be guessing.

Comment: Please improve your accept rating.

Comment: all done. can you help me now? maybe there is a name for such "generated" pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check, that the [QUrl](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qurl.html) is constructed correctly from your `QString`. The Difference between the first URL (which seems to work) and the actual is that you now have QueryItems.

If that does not give a clue, try sniffing the traffic (e.g. using [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), formerly known as ethereal)  to see the transmitted request as well as its answer.

Comment: @user907406 I'm just curious, what was the problem?

Comment: Site rejected any requests unless you specify User-Agent header. Set it to "PHP robots" and it went ok.

Comment: IC, so it was their faulty behavior.

Comment: You should *really* consider upgrading to Wireshark. We changed the name of the project from Ethereal to Wireshark in 2006.

Comment: @GeraldCombs I actually use Wireshark but still get confused the the names.